# Subscription payment in iOS

Tags: ios, paypal, in-app-purchase

Can I use some 3rd party payment gateway like PayPal for subscription purpose in an iOS app?

Comment: Till now, what you have searched on google and what you got??

Comment: @dahiya_boy I google but I found this answer, https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/78081,

Comment: Below answer is absolutely right.

Comment: @ilesh - are you looking for same? want to provide Storage space?

Comment: @Dev_Tandel, like Membership subscription but my app is on android, iOS, Web.

Comment: @ilesh - Let me share you a scenario, I was working with a client he wanted to share the music of the new artist, Absolutely free of cost. The user just need to scan QR they have and Audio file will get downloaded to their mobile. Apple rejected my apps 18 Times, even there was no any payment. They stated that you might be selling this subscription. Apple is very strict especially regarding Payments.

Comment: @Dev_Tandel, so what is the solution for the above scenario?

Comment: @ilesh -  Simply check how Netflix, amazon prime are doing. May you archive with same.

Comment: @ilesh - They too have In-App purchase for the subscription.

Comment: @Dev_Tandel, Thanks for explanation, :)

Comment: @ilesh - It helped you is what i wanted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your primary Question answer is **NO**.

***You can't accept third-party payment for content within your app.***

If you do your app will get rejected.

Yes, you can accept third-party payments for Goods sell outside of the App.

> 3.1 Payments
>
> 3.1.1 In-App Purchase:
>
> If you want to unlock features or functionality within your app, (by
>   way of example: subscriptions, in-game currencies, game levels, access
>   to premium content, or unlocking a full version), **you must use in-app
>   purchase.** Apps may use in-app purchase currencies to enable customers
>   to “tip” digital content providers in the app. Apps and their metadata
>   may not include buttons, external links, or other calls to action that
>   direct customers to purchasing mechanisms other than in-app purchase.

Here is link to all guideline, may it help you further: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#payments